# How can i retrieve both nested and nonnested children from parent html using xpath?

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath

I am creating a web crawler using python. The html being parsed seems has some strings that are directly in the parent tag here's how it looks:

```
<div class="chapter-content3">
<noscript>...stuff here filtered successfully</noscript>
<center>...stuff here filtered successfully</center>
<h4>..stuff here shows</h4>
<p>...stuff here shows</h4>
<br>
"this stuff here doesnt show"
<br>
"this neither"
 <p>..stuff here shows</p>
 </div>
```

My xpath is this:

```
//div[@class="chapter-content3"]/*[not(self::noscript) and not(self::center) and not(@class="row")]
```

Which brings up everything but not the string directly inside

How should i construct the xpath to bring up everything including the strings directly inside the parent

Comment: do you want to have all in one xpath?

Comment: @Edwin As far as the result html is in the same order as the input html. Any solution is okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost correct. Here:

```
//div[@class="chapter-content3"]/*[
   not(self::noscript) and not(self::center) and not(@class="row")
]
```

the `*` only selects actual elements. You want to select *all nodes*, which would be

```
//div[@class="chapter-content3"]//node()[
   not(self::noscript) and not(self::center) and not(@class="row")
]
```

or, a bit shorter

```
//div[@class="chapter-content3"]//node()[
   not(self::noscript or self::center or @class="row")
]
```

or, a different way of thinking about it - all text nodes except the ones with the wrong ancestry:

```
//div[@class="chapter-content3"]//text()[
   not(ancestor::noscript or ancestor::center or ancestor::*/@class="row")
]
```